# Как забрать последнее rowid из БД?

Tags: python, aiogram, sqlite3

Что надо указать, чтобы бот забрал последней **rowid** из бд, если он пополнит таблицу?

```
@dp.message_handler(Text(equals="Начать работу"))
async def get_last_ads(message: types.Message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('exemple.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    select_sql = "SELECT * FROM exemple ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;"
    results = cur.execute(select_sql)
    for row in results:
        ids = int(row[1])
        link = str(row[2])
        # print(link, ids)
        info = f"{ids}\n{link}"
        if ids not in ids_trash:
            ids_trash.append(ids)
            await message.bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, info)
```

While True - не подходит. Так как забирает последний **rowid** и постоянно обращается к бд , до тех пор пока не появится новый, а это лишняя нагрузка.

Comment: от sqlite лучше сразу со старта отказывайтесь. для многопользовательского использования он не подойдет

Comment: что лучше использовать в дальнейшем ?

Comment: @Excellent, посмотрите в сторону MariaDB, или MySQL для начала. (А потом втянетесь и Вас будет не остановить) ;-)))

Comment: @Excellent, по сабжу. https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html `SQLite keeps track of the largest ROWID using an internal table named "sqlite_sequence". The sqlite_sequence table is created and initialized automatically whenever a normal table that contains an AUTOINCREMENT column`